# Creating Unique Values based off Two Sets of Sequential Integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

First off, I apologize if this is the wrong board. I'm a heavy StackOverflow user, and this is *technically* a programming question (or at least serves programming use), but I find it to be based moreso in math.

I have two sets of sequential integers that relate to each other, for the sake of example, defined as such:

```
Set A: [1..50]
Set B: [1..150]
```

I need to generate a third set from a combination of these two sets, with unique values. All integers from `Set A` must be programmatically paired with all integers from `Set B` to create `Set C`, which will contain **unique** integers. Jumping right into it, I thought "Well, just add the two to together!" I found quickly that such an idea wasn't even close to feasible.

```
Set A   Set B   Set C
-----   -----   -----
1       1       2
1       2       3 *
1       3       4 *
2       1       3 *
2       2       4 *
2       3       5

*Non-unique Values
```

Multiplication didn't go so well either...

```
Set A   Set B   Set C
-----   -----   -----
1       1       1
1       2       2 *
1       3       3 
2       1       2 *
2       2       4 
2       3       6

*Non-unique Values
```

So I'm looking for an operator or small formula to put between `Set A` and `Set B` to generate a unique, integral `Set C`.

**EDIT**

Both sets will have values added to them over time, so I need a solution that could handle an infinitely large `Set A` and `Set B`

Comment: I'm apparently not smart enough to have posted this here... :) I'm sure your answers are right, but I have no idea what they mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just $ c = 150a + b$? Or $c=150(a-1)+b$ if you want it to be $1$-based.

(From a coding point of view, that's how indexing into packed multidimensional arrays work).

---

**Edit** after question was updated: If both of your sets are effectively all of $\mathbb N$, you can use something like
$$ c = \frac{(a+b-1)(a+b-2)}{2} + a $$
which assumes the lowest possible value for $a$ and $b$ is $1$. If the value sets are $0$-based, use
$$ \tag{*} c = \frac{(a+b)(a+b+1)}{2} + a $$
If $a$ and/or $b$ can be negative, first map them to 0-based ones using, for example,
$$ x\mapsto\begin{cases} 2x & \text{if }x\ge 0  \\ -1-2x & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases} $$
and then use $(\text{*})$.

Comment: I assume 150 to be the count of the greater set? Theoretically, both sets could be infinite, I'll update my question

Comment: answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Any bijection from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ will work. Or, for the purposes of finding sources on the internet, the slightly modified version: Any bijection from $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{N}$ will work, where $a $ from Set A and $b$ from Set B is associated to the natural number that corresponds to $a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ in the bijection.

Comment: Forgive my lack of math skills, but how does that translate to common programming operators?

Comment: @KyleMacey Sorry I was unsure of your background. I don't know about the programming details, but the idea is simple. You want to take a pair of positive integers $(a,b)$ and associate them uniquely to a third, $c.$ One way to do this is as Henning Makholm describes in his post. There are other ways to do this that are more obvious from a mathematical viewpoint (such as diagonalization) but they are probably harder to implement in a program.

Comment: +1 because I believe you :) I was able to translate Henning's answer, though. Thank you.

Comment: The $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb N$ variant doesn't quite work -- it maps $(a=1, b=2)$ and $(a=2, b=4)$ to the same number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ahh that's true, I forgot about that because the usual ways I enumerate the rationals is by enumerating $\mathbb{N}^2$ and then deleting the repeats.

Comment: I thought as much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other possible solutions:

- $c = 2^a 3^b$ (results in a very large $c$)
- Write $a,b$ in binary, and interleave the bits (or bytes, or larger chunks)
- Consider the complex integer $a+ib$ and express it in [base $2i$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base)
- Express $a,b$ in [binary-coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and concatenate them, separated by some nibble such as F which cannot appear in BCD

Of course, in most cases, the right solution for a program would be for the elements of set C not to be integers, but some aggregate type: in C, something like `struct { int a,b; }`; in C++, `pair`; in Perl, a list (or perhaps the string "\$a,\$b"); et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Each integer has a sequence representation derived from its prime factorization, e.g.,
$$
F(15) = F(2^0 3^1 5^1) = [0,1,1,...].
$$
Interleave the representations of $a$ and $b$, then convert back to an integer, to obtain a unique integer associated with $(a,b)$.
$$
F(32) = F(2^5) = [5,...].
$$
$$
[0,1,1,...] \oplus [5,...] = [0,5,1,0,1,...].
$$
$$
F^{-1}(F(15)\oplus F(32))=F^{-1}([0,5,1,0,1,...])=2^0 3^5 5^1 7^0 11^1=13365.
$$

Comment: This is _true_, but since the OP was looking for something that can be implemented in practice and factoring is (thought to be) hard, I don't think it is the solution for him.