# Map 3 Integers to a Unique Value

Tags: matrices, functions

Although the question I have is for a computer program I am writing, it is really a math question. Anyways, I have three integers. The first one is from 1-3, the second 1-2, and the third 1-2, so 12 unique combinations of the three numbers. How can I map these three numbers to a unique number between 1 and 12? This is the closest I found: [Creating Unique Values based off Two Sets of Sequential Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158731/creating-unique-values-based-off-two-sets-of-sequential-integers), but I can't figure out how to apply it to 3 numbers.

Comment: Think of the mapping as a positional number system with a variable base. So, instead of, say, successive powers of two, each place is a multiple of the total number of values in the preceding places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\in\{1,2,3\}$, $b\in\{1,2\}$, and $c\in\{1,2\}$, then $4(a-1)+2(b-1)+(c-1)+1\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$. (The $\pm1$ corrections are necessary because $1$-indexing is worse than $0$-indexing on a deeply moral level.)

Comment: +1 for the answer with a symbolic extra +1 on your moral fortitude on indexing ethics.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! Ironically, the values are actually 0 indexed (because it's accessing an item in an array), but I changed them all by one because I thought it would make more sense in a math discussion. (I therefore removed the +-1s.)